# WordPress Multiple do shortcode filter

Tags: php, wordpress, filter

Looked around and could not find anything relating to this. Attempting to run multiple instances of the do shortcode filter on a WordPress website to pre populate some form values in a web form.

Still working our way through this and getting some errors. How would we combine them and avoid duplicate function errors and other related issues?

A current working example of a single do shortcode filter, this alone works:

```
add_filter('gform_field_value_Leadsource', 'my_custom_population_function');
function my_custom_population_function($value){
return do_shortcode('[Leadsource]');
}
```

How would we combine the following do shortcode filters into one single bit of code? A copy and paste example would be so helpful.

```
add_filter('gform_field_value_Leadsource', 'my_custom_population_function');
function my_custom_population_function($value){
return do_shortcode('[Leadsource]');
}
add_filter('gform_field_value_First', 'my_custom_population_function');
function my_custom_population_function($value){
return do_shortcode('[i4w_db_FirstName]');
}
add_filter('gform_field_value_Last', 'my_custom_population_function');
function my_custom_population_function($value){
return do_shortcode('[i4w_db_LastName]');
}
add_filter('gform_field_value_Email', 'my_custom_population_function');
function my_custom_population_function($value){
return do_shortcode('[i4w_db_Email]');
}
```

Thank you to anyone who can help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this should do the trick (PHP 5.3 or higher):

```
add_action( 'init', 'so27284262_shortcode_init' );
function so27284262_shortcode_init()
{
    $xref = array(
        'Leadsource'    => 'Leadsource',
        'First'         => 'i4w_db_FirstName',
        'Last'          => 'i4w_db_LastName',
        'Email'         => 'i4w_db_Email'
    );

    foreach( $xref as $name => $cb ) {
        add_filter( 'gform_field_value_' . $name, function( $value ) use ( $cb ) {
            return do_shortcode( "[$cb]" );
        } );
    }
}
```